# Custom ActionResult to return View = Model is ReadOnly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, actionresult

I've got a snippet of code in a custom ActionResult

**VB.NET Version**

```
Dim result As New ViewResult()
result.Model= data   ## Property Model is ReadOnly
Return result
```

**C# Version**

```
ViewResult result = new ViewResult();
result.Model = data;  // Property Model is ReadOnly
return result;
```

How do I properly return a `View` from within a custom `ActionResult` that can also include the model?

Comment: Are you trying to programmatically execute a view?

Comment: Yup. Essentially I need to create a custom ActionResult (I'm calling it `Restful` whereby it checks the Request.ContentType and returns the appropriate format (Html, Json, Xml)

Comment: Ah, that's not really supported. It's possible but not very easy. I have an answer somewhere that will get you in the right direction. Check this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808076/using-the-razor-view-engine-in-a-different-way/3815216#3815216

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting

```
result.ViewData.Model = data;
```

Should help you. In fact, `get ViewResultBase.Model`  is implemented as

```
public object Model 
{
   get {
          return ViewData.Model;
       }
}
```