# Using RazorViewEngine's transformation functionality in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I do have some text(template), which looks like "Hello @FirstName, Welcome to @Address". The original plan was to put this text file in a view-bag and pass it through razor and it will do the job.

Now, The problem that I am facing is that my team wants this transformation to be handled by a Service, So there is no controller and there is no view here BUT there is a need to use Razor view engine's capability to replace all @ with server variables.

This sounded weird to me as well but is there any way that I can extract this capability of Razor view in a way that I can use this functionality in a restful service rather than sending this data to a .cshtml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible indeed.

Rick Strahl blogged about [hosting the Razor Engine](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/Dec/27/Hosting-the-Razor-Engine-for-Templating-in-NonWeb-Applications) in non-web applications.

And of course, this has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808076/using-the-razor-view-engine-in-a-different-way) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808348/using-razor-without-mvc) before.

Comment: Actually, I visited the blog and I liked it but he does not mention anywhere that where did he get reference for RazorTemplateBase? i have no idea if I need to download a package or something?

Comment: @Californicated -  He does mention it, under the "Installing The Razor Template Engine" heading. Taken from http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx

Comment: The only razor app in the library that I can see is razorC.Net. is it the one?

Comment: Actually, I came across something called @razorEngineon following URL:http://razorengine.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Quick%20Start%20Guide&referringTitle=Documentation. It's awesome and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possbible. The necessary steps to do that is described here: [Razor View Engine without MVC at all](http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/29/razor-view-engine-without-mvc-at-all/).